# overloaded methods in Trait error Spark Scala

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, overloading

I have some code

```
trait Reader {
  def read(spark: SparkSession, format: String, path: String): DataFrame
  def read[T: Encoder](spark: SparkSession, format: String, path: String): Dataset[T]
}

class LocalReader extends Reader {

  override def read[T: Encoder](spark: SparkSession, format: String, path: String): Dataset[T] = {
    spark.read
      .format(format)
      .option("header", "true")
      .load(getClass.getResource(path).getPath)
      .as[T]
  }

  override def read(spark: SparkSession, format: String, path: String): DataFrame = {
    spark.read
      .format(format)
      .option("header", "true")
      .load(getClass.getResource(path).getPath)
  }
}


object TopNSimilarCustomers extends SparkJob {
  override def appName: String = "TopNSimilarCustomers"

  override def run(spark: SparkSession, args: Array[String], reader: Reader): Unit = {

    /**
      * Only I/O here
      */

    if (args.length == 0)
      return
    val rawData = reader.read(spark, "json", "/spark-test-data.json")
    val res     = transform(spark, rawData, args(0))

  }
```

I'm getting an error at `val rawData = reader.read(spark, "json", "/spark-test-data.json")` cannot resolve overloaded method read.

So I want to have Readers/Writers for different purposes LocalReader/S3Reader and since it can return DF and DS I write an overloaded method even I have to use one. And eventually, have to implement both. Any way to avoid it?

How can I achieve what I'm trying to do? any other way or a better way etc? 
how to fix the error?

Comment: You're only giving it 2 arguments, whereas it also expects a `SparkSession` object. Also, why don't you just rename your methods instead of having 2 of them with the same signature?

Comment: sorry, typo, updated. it still gives the same error

Comment: Try renaming your 2 read methods to something like `readDataFrame` and `readDataSet`

Comment: You don't need two method with the same signature in trait, Just implement it two times

Comment: yes, that would work but I thought there is a way to only implement one of the overloaded methods?

Comment: @El. they don't have the same signature

Comment: @Sam, actually, they do. The type parameter doesn't count

Comment: BTW, you can implement the `readDataset` as `read(spark, format, path).as[T]`

Comment: ok. so if I remove the return type I can use the same function for multiple return types? Of course not in this case because DataSet needs a T type. but in general?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez bingo! thanks. haha missed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for getting `cannot resolve overloaded method read.` is Reader trait has two methods both will take same number of params.

To solve this issue rename method names something like for example `readDF & readDS` or you can also check below code & modify as per your requirement.

```
    case class ReadConfig(format: String,path: String,options: Map[String,String])
    case class WriteConfig(format: String,path: String,options: Map[String,String])
    case class Config(read: ReadConfig,write: WriteConfig)

    trait Writer {
      def write(df: DataFrame): Unit
    }
    trait Reader {
      def read: DataFrame
    }

    trait RW extends Reader with Writer {
      val spark : SparkSession
      val config : Config
    }

    // Add logic for Local
    class Local(override val spark: SparkSession,override val config: Config) extends RW {
      override def read: DataFrame = {
        spark.read
          .format(config.read.format)
          .options(config.read.options)
          .load(config.read.path)
      }
      override def write(df: DataFrame): Unit = {
        df.write
          .format(config.write.format)
          .options(config.write.options)
          .save(config.write.path)
      }
    }

// Add logic for S3
 class S3(override val spark: SparkSession,override val config: Config) extends RW {
      override def read: DataFrame = {
        spark.read
          .format(config.read.format)
          .options(config.read.options)
          .load(config.read.path)
      }
      override def write(df: DataFrame): Unit = {
        df.write
          .format(config.write.format)
          .options(config.write.options)
          .save(config.write.path)
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I like the idea. I had something similar in mind for the writer or something like storage/IO with does both. I'll implement it soon. 
It's my first spark application/project :D

Comment: You cant update the config once the object is made. What if I want to write at two different locations during the job or different formats? have to create a new object each time

Comment: yes, I understand that but I think rather than making them a var, putting them into arguments of the read/write would be better either separate or config. What do you think?

Comment: Read function needs two and write one main things. location and format. Rest are optional so the optional can go into the map. No need to write extra code when simply the argument would work.

Comment: If you ask me I will not put logic to write into two different locations, that code is not generic and that to your code will be writing data sequence mode. Instead create two object with different values and invoke write method parallel.. think on this..